# Array of Json coming from api response

Tags: python, api

I am trying to automate a rest API response with different values to pass and append those responses in a single file.

For example https://localhost:8080?sid=123 gives a response :

```
[
    {
        "WRITESTAMP": "2020-01-28T03:56:11Z",
        "RECEIVESTAMP": "2018-08-29T15:11:45Z",
    }
]
```

https://localhost:8080?sid=1234 gives a difference response :

```
[
    {
        "WRITESTAMP": "2020-01-28T03:56:11Z",
        "RECEIVESTAMP": "2018-08-29T15:11:45Z",
    }
]
```

I need these to be appended into a single text file in json format. Since these are arrays coming so i am not getting a proper json.

```
[[
    {
        "WRITESTAMP": "2020-01-28T03:56:11Z",
        "RECEIVESTAMP": "2018-08-29T15:11:45Z",
    }
],

[
    {
        "WRITESTAMP": "2020-01-28T03:56:11Z",
        "RECEIVESTAMP": "2018-08-29T15:11:45Z",
    }
]
]
```

Ideally i should get :

```
[
  {
        "WRITESTAMP": "2020-01-28T03:56:11Z",
        "RECEIVESTAMP": "2018-08-29T15:11:45Z",
    },

 {
        "WRITESTAMP": "2020-01-28T03:56:11Z",
        "RECEIVESTAMP": "2018-08-29T15:11:45Z",
    }
]
```

Comment: Append only the index 0 of each output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sids = [123, 1234]
api_uri = "https://localhost:8080?sid={}"
response = []
for sid in sids:
    response = request.get(api_uri.format(sid))
    responses.append(response.json[0])
```

then add it on the file

```
import json

with open(<filename>) as file_handler:
    json.dump(responses, file_handler, indent=2)
```

Answer (score 0):

this shuld work for you

```
my_api_urls= ["https://localhost:8080?sid=123", "https://localhost:8080?sid=1234"]
responses=[]
for i in my_api_urls:
    responses.append(requests.get(i).json()[0])
```